KINGSTER WiFi 6E Card, 5.2 Tri-Band 5400 Mbps Wireless Module for Laptop Support Windows 10/11 64bit Pci. Can I get any drivers for this
KINGSTER WiFi 6E Card, 5.2 Tri-Band 5400 Mbps Wireless Module for Laptop Support Windows 10/11 64bit Pci.  Can I get any drivers for this

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/204836/intel-wifi-6e-ax210-gig/downloads.html Intel Wireless Wi-Fi Firmware Firmware usually ships with your Linux* OS distribution, or you can download it from the above links or from the Firmware git tree. Additional Information available in Linux* Support for Intel® Wireless Adapters
